# How can I prove a limit is infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

How can I prove that the $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x^2}{x-1}=\infty$ using the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition of a limit?
I think I start with $\forall$M>0, want $\delta$>0. After that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show: $\forall \epsilon >0 \; \exists \delta>1$ such that: $\delta>x>1 \implies$ $\frac{x^2}{x-1} > \epsilon$.

Note that the function is non-increasing (monotonous) on $[1,2]$.
Therefore it is sufficient to just ask for a $1 < \delta <2$ with the property that: $\frac{\delta^2}{\delta-1} > \epsilon$. The condition above is then automatically true for any $1 < x < \delta$.

$ \delta = \frac{1}{2} (\epsilon+\sqrt{\epsilon-4} \sqrt{\epsilon})$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: Shouldn't I be using x somewhere in this?

Comment: All that would mean is that $\frac{x^2}{x-1}$ has arbitrarily large values close to 1, which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: @user73985 ups, fixed the condition on $\delta$

Comment: @Claudia yes of course, fixed

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that

$$\forall M \in \mathbb{R} \exists \delta s.t. \delta > x > 1 \implies \frac{x^2}{x-1} > M$$

Comment: For a previous problem where $\frac{1}{x}>M$ I chose $\delta$=$\frac{1}{M}$ but I don't understand what to do here since there are variables in the numerator and denominator

Comment: Does noticing $\frac{x^2}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x-1}$ for $x>1$ help you?

Comment: Can I say $\frac{x^2}{x-1}>\frac{1}{x-1}>M$

Comment: You need to pick $\delta $ such that that second inequality is true.

Answer (score 0):

With $x=1+\delta$ for $\delta>0$, we can write
$$
\frac{x^2}{x-1}=x+1+\frac{1}{x-1}=2+\delta+\frac{1}{\delta}
$$
so for any $M>0$, we only need to pick $\delta\in(0,\frac{1}{M})$ (say, $\frac{1}{2M}$) to ensure that the RHS above is greater than $M$.